# ¿Cómo hacer una estructura genérica? C#

Tags: c#, estructuras-de-datos, genericos

Tengo qué hacer un programa para la siguiente situación:
[image: Problema sobre estructura genérica]

Pero no sé qué deba hacer en sí, a lo que entendí fue que debo hacer una clase genérica (donde se usa el < T>) y ahí hacer el proceso, luego mandar llamar todo en la clase principal. También sé que se pueden hacer más clases de ser necesario, pero no entiendo hmm... Lo que tengo qué hacer principalmente, quizás alguien lo entienda mejor. Por favor.

Esta es mi clase llamada Generica. En la parte de *//Imprimir* supongo que debo hacer un método para que me imprima todo, y ya solo lo llamo en la clase principal, pero no sé cómo imprimirlo o qué debo de imprimir (Estoy perdido, pues no comprendo el problema):

```
 public class Generica<T>
    {
        //Atributos
        public String titulo { get; set; }
        public T[] contenido{ get; set; }

        //Constructor
        public Generica (int temasContenido)
        {
            contenido = new T[temasContenido];
        }

        //Imprimir

    }
```

Esta es mi clase llamada Libros, en la cual establecí algunos atributos, lo mismo pensaba hacer con otra clase llamada Videos, y otra llamada Periodicos:

```
class Libros
    {
        //Atributos

        private String editorial;
        private String autor;
        public int numPaginas;

        //Constructor
        public Libros (String editorial, String autor, int numPaginas)
        {

            this.editorial = editorial;
            this.autor = autor;
            this.numPaginas = numPaginas;
        }

        //Editorial
        public void setEditorial (String editorial)
        {
            this.editorial = editorial;
        }
        public String getEditorial()
        {
            return "Editorial del libro: " + editorial;
        }

        //Autor
        public void setAutor (String autor)
        {
            this.autor = autor;
        }
        public String getAutor()
        {
            return "Autor: " + autor;
        }

        //NumPaginas
        public void setNumPaginas (int numPaginas)
        {
            this.numPaginas = numPaginas;
        }
        public String getNumPaginas()
        {
            return "Número de páginas: " + numPaginas;
        }


    }
```

Yo supongo que tengo qué conectar esas 2 cosas de alguna manera y mandarlas llamar en la clase principal, sobre todo tengo que usar el < T> de la clase Generica (para que sea una verdadera clase genérica), y pues es todo, no entiendo qué es lo que tengo que hacer en sí, espero que alguien lo entienda, recién estoy comenzando a leer sobre este tema y aún no lo comprendo. Gracias.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque aquí no se realizan tareas de instituto/universidad cuando carecen de código e intentos por resolver el problema.

Comment: No es una tarea de un instituto, estudio por mi cuenta y tengo intentos de lo que creí que se tenía que hacer, en seguida lo agrego a la publicación

Comment: Perfecto Kevin, si ese es el caso, con gusto te apoyamos :D

Comment: Vale, ya edité la publicación, gracias por la advertencia! :D

Comment: La pregunta no es mala.. pero el problema planteado es muy extraño. Que seria una estructura generica? estas seguro que necesita ser de tipo T? no podria ser una clase "cosa" que tenga las caracteristicas basicas de esas tres cosas? como nombre, fecha de adquisicion, donde esta guardado.. no podria ni responder, porque no se que piden.. yo tampoco lo entiendo. Capaz por desgracia es el caso en que hay que ver la respuesta para saber de que estan hablando..

Comment: Tiene que ser forzosamente de tipo < T>, yo también creí que solo sería una clase librería con los atributos generales, y que ya solo se heredaba a Libros, Videos y Periodicos, pero no, debe ser de tipo T. Eso de tipo T es para por ejemplo, en lugar de hacer un arreglo de String para nombre y autor, y otro de tipo int para numeroPaginas, an el arrelgo de T se pueden combinar los tipos de datos.

Comment: Mira.. creo que no tiene nada que ver lo generico con lo que vos decis. El arreglo ya es de tipo T sin que tengas que hacer una clase para ello. Mas alla de eso, veo que hay un grave error en como planteas las propiedas. esto es C#, los get y set son automaticos, una propiedad se escribe como public int numPaginas {get; set;} y no tenes que hacer un set y un get para la misma, accedes directo... No se donde viste esa forma de escribir las propiedades.

Comment: Y no, no entiendo el problema de los genericos aca, que es como se llama a T. no hay nada generico aca. Lo generico se usa para poder hacer algo sobre una estructura que puede tener cualquier tipo de objeto adentro.. Capaz podrias generalizar un estante? igual, sigo sin entender el punto

Comment: Es mas yo iria mas lejos.. y mas alla del tutorial que estes haciendo. Si no encuentras la forma de meter un generico ahi, entonces es que no va y estas forzando el codigo a mas no poder...

Comment: Kevin, estas seguro que el planteo no se refiere a crear una interface, heredar 3 clases de la misma, y usar `List<T>` de esa interface?

Comment: yo creo que simple y sencillamente te están pidiendo una clase `biblioteca` y otra `elementoBiblioteca` la cual tiene un atributo que se llame `tipoElemento` y en este tipo de elemento puede ser: "video", "libro", "periodico". Dado que si es ese todo el enunciado ni siquiera se puede llegar a algo que nos diga que crees una clase "generica" (una clase elemental. Ej: ElementoBiblioteca) y después crear sus clases tipo o de herencia (Libro, Video, Periódico). Como yo veo el problema, se refiere a que crees una estructura orientada a objetos y luego la lleves a código

Comment: Gracias por todo chicos, finalmente pude hacer el programa con algunas de sus sugerencias, díganme si quieren verlo! :D